# How can I compile C++11 code with Orwell Dev-C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, dev-c++

Trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Foo {
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::Foo\n"; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo\n"; }
    void bar() { std::cout << "Foo::bar\n"; }
};

void f(const Foo &foo)
{
    std::cout << "f(const Foo&)\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> p1(new Foo);  // p1 owns Foo
    if (p1) p1->bar();

    {
        std::unique_ptr<Foo> p2(std::move(p1));  // now p2 owns Foo
        f(*p2);

        p1 = std::move(p2);  // ownership returns to p1
        std::cout << "destroying p2...\n";
    }

    if (p1) p1->bar();

    // Foo instance is destroyed when p1 goes out of scope
}
```

with Orwell Dev-c++ 5.3.0.3 yields the following error:

> 'unique_ptr' is not a member of 'std'.

How can I handle this?

Comment: I don't have the mentioned IDE, but I suspect the code example could be trimmed down quite a bit, possibly to something like `#include <memory> int main () { std::unique_ptr<int> p;}`. That would greatly reduce the unnecessary clutter in your post.

Comment: Install a recent C++11 compatible compiler, e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Answer (score 11):

Please make sure you supply the correct -std flag when compiling. The default setting that Orwell Dev-C++ uses (don't pass any -std option), will not enable some shiny new C++11 functions, like unique_ptr. The fix is quite simple:

- For non-project compilations, go to: Tools >> Compiler Options >> (select your compiler) >> Settings >> Code Generation >> (set 'Language standard' to a C++11 option)
- For project compilations, go to: Project >> Compiler >> Code Generation >> (set 'Language standard' to a C++11 option)

Here's a bit more information about the -std flag:
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options

As you can see, GCC uses a GNU dialect of C++03 by default (which doesn't seem to support unique_ptr).

Comment: I have one more problem when selecting Language standard as GNU C++11, it gives me "unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"

Comment: Try selecting the GNU C++ standard. Looks like I need to update the ISO C++11 flags to 'c++11' from 'c++0x'.

Comment: Have you been able to get this working ? 
I installed the latest Dev-C++ 5.4.2 , but still get "unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x" errors when I try to enable c++11.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of [Dev-C++](https://github.com/Embarcadero/Dev-Cpp) comes with TDM-GCC 9.2.0 which defaults to C++17.