# C++ Converting a String to Double

Tags: c++, string, class, double

I've been trying to find the solution for this all day! You might label this as re-post but what I'm really looking for is a solution **without using boost lexical cast**. A traditional C++ way of doing it would be great. I tried this code but it returns a set of gibberish numbers and letters.

```
string line; 
double lineconverted;

istringstream buffer(line);
lineconverted;
buffer >> lineconverted;
```

And I alse tried this, but it ALWAYS returns 0.

```
stringstream convert(line);
if ( !(convert >> lineconverted) ) {
    lineconverted  = 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: For the first solution I used (gibberish).. Here's a snapshot
[image]

Comment: "gibberish numbers and letter", all in a double variable? How?

Comment: What is the contents of `line`?

Comment: A double value "50000"

Comment: @MD.Unicorn I posted a pic

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert string to double in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392981/how-can-i-convert-string-to-double-in-c)

Comment: Did you ever tried to use *atof* function? Or just decided to use pure stringstream. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4754486/1406063

Comment: Regarding your code: You realize that `string line` is default-initialized, so it's empty?

Comment: I tried atof as well, still doesnt return the double value which is 50000, it displays '0', even when I used atof

Comment: @jogojapan I havent shown the complete code. It reads from a file line by line. Thus the name, line :) It is not empty

Comment: That "gibberish" in the image is not gibberish, it is a way of representing a very small number: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation Of course that is not the number you actually wanted.

Comment: Oh I see.. you have trouble reading the scientific notation.... You can use `std::cout << std::fixed << lineconverted` to output it in the usual notation. Make sure you `#include <iomanip>`.

Comment: Are you sure the string you pass to `istringstream` isn't empty after all? If the extremely small value you get right now isn't what you expected, the cause may very well be that the strings your passing are empty, in which case the `double` won't be changed, and since you don't initialize it, it will have an unpredictable value.

Comment: Print the value of `line` to the console before converting. Obviously, there is something wrong with contents of `line`. Your code is fine.

Answer (score 13):

```
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double f = 0.0;

    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string s = "3.1415";

    ss << s;
    ss >> f;

    cout << f;
}
```

The good thing is, that this solution works for others also, like ints, etc.

If you want to repeatedly use the same buffer, you must do `ss.clear` in between.

There is also a shorter solution available where you can initialize the value to a stringstream and flush it to a double at the same time:

```
#include <sstream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   stringstream("3.1415")>>f ;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Since C++11 you could use [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) function:

```
string line; 
double lineconverted;

try
{
    lineconverted = std::stod(line);
}
catch(std::invalid_argument)
{
    // can't convert
}
```

But solution with `std::stringstream` also correct:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    double d = 0;
    iss >> d;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you have C++11 enabled?

Comment: I'm new to C++, enlighten me 'how to' please :)

Comment: @PJ_Boy: Are you using MSVS? What version?

Comment: @PJ_Boy, nice. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613295/orwell-dev-c-support-c11), it could helps you.

Comment: that uses a gcc compiler try to get it's version -- and search if it supports C++11 (c++0x).

Comment: Your catch statment is invalid

Comment: Could you clarify that, please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store (to a vector for example) all the doubles of a line

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{

  std::istream_iterator<double> in(std::cin);
  std::istream_iterator<double> eof;
  std::vector<double> m(in,eof);

  //print
  std::copy(m.begin(),m.end(),std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout,"\n"));

}
```