# How to correctly convert "strings" to "double"?

Tags: c++

The last decimal value is not converted to [double](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/double) and does not appear in the print. How to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double toDouble(const char* str)
{
   return stod(str);
}

int main()
{
    string text = "10158.34";
    double value = toDouble(text.c_str());
    cout << value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747915/c-converting-a-string-to-double

Answer (score 0):

The default output setting is to print six significant digits; see [std::setprecision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string text = "10158.34";
    double value = std::stod(text);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << value << std::endl;
}
```

which prints 10158.34000000000014551915228366851806640625, because 10158.34 can't be represented exactly as a `double`.