# how to Pass in the flag -std=c++11 flag when compiling? (using C++)

Tags: c++, flags

i am getting an error while compiling. and it says that i am supposed to enable it with

```
gnu++11 or -std=c++11
```

how to do that? i have no clue. i am using Dev 5.5.2.

Comment: This should help:

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613295/orwell-dev-c-support-c11

Comment: As a side note, please don't call it "Dev 5.5.2". At least call it "Dev-C++ 5.5.2", even better would be "Orwell Dev-C++ 5.5.2". That way, a lot more people will know what you're asking about.