# I am still getting the error 'stoi' was not declared after I set my compiler setting to support c++11. Why?

Tags: c++11, mingw, codeblocks

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string humanNo;
    int computerNo = 0;
    do{
        getline(cin,humanNo);
        computerNo = stoi(humanNo);
    }while(computerNo != 4);
}
```

I am trying to use stoi, stol to easily convert from string to integer in my CodeBlocks IDE. At first I learned that you have to first enable c++11 in the compiler settings. I enabled it but I am still getting the same error. Does anyone know what might be the problem I am encountering?

I am using MinGW compiler.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Telling us you're using the CodeBlocks IDE doesn't really help, noone cares what editor you're using, the compiler is what matters. I assume you're using the mingw compiler, in which case these functions are not available

Comment: CodeBlocks comes packaged with MinGW 4.7.1 by default. You can try something like [nuwen.net](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) (a 64-bit distro with 4.9.1, see the duplicate below), which I believe the string conversion functions work.

Comment: yes minGw. What should I do ?

Comment: @remyabel I downloaded the MinGW distro and extracted to same folder, same error :( .. please help

Comment: You could try this patch: http://paste.fedoraproject.org/161510/19042363/raw/

Comment: @JonathanWakely Umm I am sorry but how do I use this ? .. I am novice programmer sorry:(

Comment: OK, find the file `basic_string.h` in the gcc 4.7.1 installation from mingw and replace it with http://paste.fedoraproject.org/161513/4299214/raw/ -- and please comment here to let me know if that works

Comment: @Harshal I highly doubt that STL's distro is the problem. Try compiling the program using the command prompt, then read your IDE's documentation for using STL's distro instead of the one that comes with the IDE.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I already replaced it with 4.9.1 as remyabel said, i changed the basic_string.h, restarted CodeBlocks. Did not work :(

Comment: @Harshal Did you actually ensure that CodeBlocks is using the correct compiler? The patch should not be necessary for STL's distro.

Comment: @remyabel what should i do to ensure that ? thanks

Comment: @HarshalCarpenter Refer to my previous comment.

Comment: @remyabel did not find any documentation or maybe i do not know where it is :( .. but i have only GNU GCC compiler "Detected" when i start the CodeBlocks.

Comment: Why don't you use Visual Studio? mingw has many bugs, and you are going to encounter more.

Comment: @SiyuanRen Visual Studio is very heavy with those additional graphics, I am using Orwell Dev C++ now. It is supporting C++11 and working just fine.. but I am looking forward to download and setup VS in coming months. Thanks for advice :)

Comment: @SiyuanRen, Visual C++ has many bugs too

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to fix CodeBlocks for C++11 support, but I downloaded [Orwell Dev C++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/) and followed the instructions over [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613295/orwell-dev-c-support-c11). I recommend to everyone to switch to it as it will save you from lot of headache. Thank you all.

Edit: If the CodeBlocks is not working out for you guys. :)

Comment: Actually, Code Blocks works just fine. You're just inexperienced - this isn't so much criticism (everyone has to start somehwere), just a friendly reminder you probably shouldn't hand out advice until you get a much more sure footing than you have right now.

Comment: @Cubic In my case it didn't work out with the advices given by people, I still use codeblocks.. Just wasn't able to setup for C++11..