# random: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, dev-c++

I am trying to run some simulations, but when I try to compile my code I get an error that says

> random: No such file or directory

The beginning of my code looks like

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<random>
#include<set>
#include<algorithm>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;
```

I'm using Dev-C++ 5.0 beta 9.2. I should note that this code compiles just fine on my home computer.

Edit:

There is no option to change "Language standard" under my compiler options:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you compiling with the `-std=c++11` flag set?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: What toolchain do you use in Dev-C++?

Comment: @kccu See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/devcpp/) please.

Comment: My compiler options window does not look like that.http://i65.tinypic.com/2mx0eft.png

Comment: Check the C++ Compiler tab.

Comment: Not there either. http://i66.tinypic.com/23h3yuq.png

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951376/how-to-change-mode-from-c98-mode-in-dev-c-to-a-mode-that-supports-c0x-ran suggested adding "-std=C++0x" or "-std=c++11" but neither work.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add screenshots and such, I'll reopen your question afterwards. Also please provide your toolchain and its version.

Comment: I don't know what a "toolchain" is or how to determine its version.

Comment: The toolchain is the c++ compiler used by your Dev-C++ IDE.

Comment: That still doesn't help me determine its version. As I said in my question I'm running Dev-C++ 5.0 beta 9.2. Their website says "It uses Mingw port of GCC (GNU Compiler Collection) as it's compiler."

Comment: You can update your installation of MinGW to the latest version independently of what was shipped with Dev-C++ originally. May be that helps.

Comment: I just installed Dev-C++ today, so everything should be the latest version...

Comment: From [here](http://orwelldevcpp.blogspot.de/) it seems the latest Dev C++ version is 5.11. Also that doesn't mean it is shipped with the lates MinGW GCC. You can check the compiler version opening a shell window and type in `g++ --version`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by opening a shell window in Dev C++.

Comment: On windows it's the `cmd` Window (Input Prompt), I didn't mean from Dev-C++.

Comment: When I try that I get a message that says "'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Use the full path where it's installed to invoke then.

Comment: The version says "3.4.2 (mingw-special)." The real issue is that I cannot change the language standard in Dev C++ because the compiler options window does not seem to have that option. I remember changing it on my home computer without a problem.

Comment: Do you see the bit in the second screenshot where it says `-std=C++0x`? Change that to `-std=c++11` (note the case of the `C`) and see if that works. Alternatively, try just making the `C` lowercase.

Comment: When I tried that I got a message that said "unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11""

Comment: @kccu Try the flag you have with a lowercase `c` instead of an uppercase one?

Comment: The C needs to be lower case in the `-std=C++0x`

Comment: Same problem: "unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x""

Comment: What compiler is installed?  Which version? (Dev-C++ is not a compiler but an IDE for a compiler)

Comment: I have already answered that question in the comments above: Dev C++ says it uses "Mingw port of GCC (GNU Compiler Collection)." The version of g++ installed is "3.4.2 (mingw-special)."

Comment: @kccu (1) Please add that to the question, then. (2) GCC 3.4 [doesn't seem to support any C++11 features](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11).

Comment: You need a higher version of GCC then.

Comment: @kccu As mentioned earlier, the compiler version shipped with Dev-C++ isn't necessarily the latest one, and you can update it separately.

Comment: If you want to use Dev C++ as an IDE, it's probably better if you install the more recent Orwell forked version, the one linked in πάντα ῥεῖ comment above and mentioned in the Q&A you linked earlier.

Comment: I've downloaded the more recent version of C++ and was able to change the language standard. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `-std=c++11` flag to use this **C++11 Feature**! Random requires C++11 for its use.

Comment: The problem apparently is that OP doesn't know how to do that in the Dev-C++ IDE.

Comment: I tried to follow the steps here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613295/how-can-i-compile-c11-code-with-orwell-dev-c) to set this, but once I get to "Code Generation" there's no "Language standard" option

Comment: Before trying to set c++11,  OP is using Dev-C++ 5.0 beta 9.2!